# How to scroll only down direction in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I have a Pageview scroll which can be scrolled in up and down direction. Can i make it to scroll only downwards once scrolled down cannot go up . I googled but i haven't found anything useful

**Update :**

```
class _ScrollDownOnlyState extends State<ScrollDownOnly> {
  bool checkDir = false;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Down scroll"),
      ),
      body: PageView.builder(
        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
        physics: checkDir ? const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics() : const AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          print("checl $checkDir");
          return GestureDetector(
            onPanUpdate: (details) {
              print(details.delta.dy);
              if (details.delta.dy > 0) {
                setState(() {
                  checkDir = true;
                });
              }
              if (details.delta.dy < 0) {
                // set your var
                setState(() {
                  checkDir = false;
                });
              }
            },
            child: Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
              color: Colors.pink,
              child: Center(
                child: Text(
                  "${index + 1}",
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 30),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
        itemCount: 50,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I was stuck on this for a while myself (the other posted answers did not work for me) so I'm posting my solution

Whenever the user scrolls in the allowed direction, I remove from my list (`myItems` in the example) the element that's just gone offscreen. In my case, I've configured (not shown) my ListView to snap scrolls to predictable positions, such that any scroll will push exactly one element offscreen at a time (so `myItems.removeAt(0)` suffices). If you have multiple elements going offscreen at once, you'll need to keep count somehow such that you remove the number that have gone offscreen. Since I also `setState` after removing from my list, the `ListView` is updated accordingly.

```
NotificationListener(
  onNotification: (scroll) {
    if (scroll is UserScrollNotification && scroll.direction == ScrollDirection.reverse) {
       scrolling = true;
    } else if (scroll is UserScrollNotification && scroll.direction == ScrollDirection.forward) {
       scrolling = false;
    }
    if (scrolling && scroll is ScrollEndNotification && scroll.metrics.axisDirection == AxisDirection.right) {
      scrolling = false;
      setState(() {
        myItems.removeAt(0);
      });
    }   
    return true;
  },
  child: ListView(
           key: ObjectKey(myItems),
           children: myItems,
           scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
         ),
)
```

Note that I also use a variable (which I've named `scrolling`) to track state. This is necessary because attempting to scroll the opposite direction still triggers a `ScrollEndNotification` in the allowed direction. I set `scrolling = true` only when the *user* has initiated a scroll in the allowed direction so that `setState` is only called upon `ScrollEndNotifications` under those conditions. More details on how ScrollNotifications work are available here: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ScrollNotification-class.html

Also note that my example does things horizontally, preventing the user from swiping left-to-right to scroll, and allowing the user to scroll by swiping from right-to-left. You can adapt this approach to vertical (up only or down only) by changing the `scrollDirection` parameter and tweaking the `ScrollDirection` and `AxisDirection` terms until you see your desired behavior.

Comment: Well said bro! :D

Answer (score 1):

You could for example use a var `scrollDir` and apply it to the `PageView`

```
physics: scrollDir ? const  NeverScrollableScrollPhysics() : const AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
```

With `NeverScrollableScrollPhysics()` youre blocking the scroll abillity. With `AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics()` you're activating scrolling features.

You would get full control with a `GestureDetector` detecting up or down scrolling. It could maybe look something like this in total:

```
PageView(
            children: <Widget>[
              // Add children here
              GestureDetector(
                  onPanUpdate: (details) {
                    if (details.delta.dy > 0) {
                      setState(() {
                        checkDir = true;
                      });
                    }
                    if (details.delta.dy < 0) {
                      // set your var
                      checkDir = false;
                    }
                  },
                  child: Container(child: Text('MY WIDGETS')))
            ],
            physics: checkDir
                ? const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics()
                : const AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
          )),
```

Scrollphysics doc: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ScrollPhysics-class.html

GestureDetector doc: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GestureDetector-class.html

Comment: Can i apply this one in pageview.builder ? @MarcelDz

Comment: nearly the same. you would put the gesture detector above your itembuilder widget

Comment: please mark it as answer for other users if I helped you

Comment: Sure. I'll try it and let you know

Comment: It's not working .I've added the code have a look @Marcel Dz

Comment: you forgot to use setstate at  if (details.delta.dy < 0)

Comment: Even after adding `setstate` . I can scroll up i've updated the latest code @Marcel Dz

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own scrollphysics overriding applyPhysicsToUserOffset.

```
  @override
  double applyPhysicsToUserOffset(ScrollMetrics position, double offset) {
    return offset > 0 ? 0 : offset;
  }
```

Then in your pageview instantiate your CustomScrollPhysics